# New EIN when adding managing member to Wyoming LLC

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, irs

I own a WY LLC as a sole member, and am adding my spouse as the second managing member. I understand that in addition to changing the LLC's operating agreement, I also must apply to a new EIN given that the LLC's status at the IRS changes from sole proprietorship to a partnership.

**Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction in applying for this new EIN?**

I know it can be done online, but I'm getting confused with the torrent of forms and links from the IRS. I'd very much appreciate any inputs, especially from someone who has done it before.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend - and the IRS site is easy to navigate via search.

[Apply for an Employer Identification Number (EIN) Online](https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Apply-for-an-Employer-Identification-Number-(EIN)-Online)

Comment: Weren't we trying to avoid giyf answers? (Not objecting, I think this is often the moist useful answer, but SE is officially concerned that URIs might become obsolete and generally grumbles about "can you include the essentials here.")

Comment: I agree. Not sure how to edit this. One can apply for EIN on line. Maybe I should have offered the main link irs.gov and said once on the site, search on EIN? I'm open to suggestions.